# How to attach a file in email or save it to external device storage in Titanium apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

An user need to receive a small text file generated inside the Titanium app.

I'm trying to send an email with this file in attachments, but the documentation doesn't help me to achieve this.

I'm using Ti.Cloud.Emails to send emails.

Another approach was to save the file in the Filesystem, but I'm using the code below and I can't find the file.

```
file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile( Ti.Filesystem.applicationCacheDirectory,'file.csv');
    alert(file.resolve());
    file.write('any text\n');
```

The alert gives the path: file:///data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/file.csv

Yes, I tried to use the Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory

Still, I can't find the file, Does someone knows where the file is?. Is there another better way to give to the user the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Titanium docs pretty much tells how to send email and how to add attachments into it.

***First of all note that to send email, you need to run the app only on device and device must have an email account configured.***

Here is the sample code for you to send email with attachments:

```
var text_data = 'This is your data to write inside the text file.'

// you can either use applicationDataDirectory or tempDirectory
var textFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'your_file.txt');
    textFile.write(text_data);

var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();

var msg = "This is the message written in the body of the email content.";       

emailDialog.subject = "Titanium Rocks!";
emailDialog.toRecipients = ['abc_123@gmail.com'];
emailDialog.messageBody = msg;
emailDialog.addAttachment(textFile);
emailDialog.open();
```

- Now if you are trying to find the file on device using any File Explorer, then you cannot find them this way because these directories are not available to public users to view or to modify (otherwise I believe anyone can steal the data of any app).

Comment: yeah, thanks, can you tell me how can I use file Explorer to find the file?

Plus, If text_data is some binary data (like some xls) in textFile.write(text_data); 

will be created xls in attachment?

cheers

Comment: You cannot find them unless you save them in externalStorage on Android only. You cannot create any doc just by giving them .xls extension or .doc or .exe. Hahaha... obviously you cannot...You can only create simple text files like .txt or .json or images also which are plain blob files. Just create a file with extension .txt or .json or .jpg or .png and write the string or blob data in it.

Comment: Yeah I know that giving the extension don't create the doc. That's right I said If text_data is some binary and written to a file, the binary would be created.

So that's it? There is no way to create binary files?